# which strategy does Hazelcast used for load balancing RMI OR THREAD MIGRATION?

Tags: java, multithreading, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I want to study Hazelcast's internal architecture for load balancing in cluster. Can somebody tell me the proper links? Does Hazelcast use RMI for load balancing ? if not then does it use Thread migration for load balancing? kindly guide me the strategy of load balancing used by HAZELCAST in cluster environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to study what Hazelcast does, check out the source from github.

Hazelcast doesn't make use of RMI but uses raw sockets. And what is thread migration?

And for load balancing: most call you don't want to load balance; you want to send them to the machine owning the data. E.g. a map.get. Hazelcast uses a master/slave replication; so of each partition there is a single master and multiple backups.